# Using python to strip phrase in a bunch of files

Tags: python, strip

I am having 29 .srt files. They all contain HTML code like `<font color="#E5E5E5">`, `<font color="#CCCCCC">`, and `</font>` in there. I want to strip all these HTML codes out from these 29 files. But I don't know how to do it at once. I've attached the code I am using right now in the question. But it can only change one file at once, and it leaves me with 3 useless files. Could anyone help me with this?

```
    import re

    string = open('/Users/Cynthia/Desktop/Jeunesse/Longivity English/Jeunesse 
    Longevity TV - Episode 27 - Lifestyle - PART 4 - Healthy Nutrition 2 
    2.en.transcribed.txt').read()
    new_str = re.sub('<font color="#CCCCCC">', ' ', string)
    open('b.txt', 'w').write(new_str)

    string = open('/Users/Cynthia/Desktop/Jeunesse/Longivity 
    English/b.txt').read()
    new_str = re.sub('<font color="#E5E5E5">', ' ', string)
    open('c.txt', 'w').write(new_str)

    string = open('/Users/Cynthia/Desktop/Jeunesse/Longivity 
    English/c.txt').read()
    new_str = re.sub('</font>', ' ', string)
    open('d.txt', 'w').write(new_str)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup library has lot's of functionality for extracting data from HTML, you might find using that library easier than this approach

Comment: Hi. You look like a programming beginner. Which is a good thing and you have a lot to learn. An important  thing in programming is to split big problems to small problems. So here you need to learn how to write a function that removes the HTML from one file - and then how to call that function with the filename for each of the 29 files.

Comment: You should resist the urge to use regular expressions to extract your html chunks. Instead you should use a html parser like lxml or BeautifulSoup. Then, if you need to you can consider using regex. The reasons for this are the html parsers are much more efficient and robust at working with html/xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a beginner's friendly way of using a function to do work on one file. It chains your code and writes the result into a new file.

So you only need to call **strip_html** once for each file with the filename and the name for a new file.

In this example there's a list of file names, and it will write the fixed file with the word ".fixed" at the end.

Please note that this is a simple way of doing it, and I left out a lot of things to make this easy to understand. Once you understand more about programming you will find much better ways. But you should get this to work.

```
import re

def strip_html(filename, newfilename):
    with open(filename) as f1:
        string = f1.read()
        new_str = re.sub('<font color="#CCCCCC">', ' ', string)
        new_str = re.sub('<font color="#E5E5E5">', ' ', new_str)
        new_str = re.sub('</font>', ' ', new_str)
        with open(newfilename, 'w') as w1:
            w1.write(new_str)

files = ['/Users/Cynthia/Desktop/Jeunesse/Longivity English/Jeunesse 
Longevity TV - Episode 27 - Lifestyle - PART 4 - Healthy Nutrition 2 
2.en.transcribed.txt',
'/Users/Cynthia/Desktop/Jeunesse/Longivity English/Jeunesse 
Longevity TV - Episode 28 - Lifestyle - PART 1 - Healthy Nutrition 3 
2.en.transcribed.txt'
]

for file in files:  
    strip_html(file, file + '.fixed')
```

Hope this helps.

When you get this to run, look at the os.listdir() command to learn how to get the list of filesnames from a directory instead of writing them here in the code.